# Different buttons take to the same mapactivity but differento location

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

what I want to do es pressing different buttons and each of them takes me to the same mapactivity but in a different area... is that posible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible if you use different `latLng` variables to animate camera.

Syntax:

```
latLng = new LatLng(double lat, double long);
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(latLng)             // Sets the center of the map to location user
    .zoom(15)                   // Sets the zoom
    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

If you change the values of `lat` and `long` variables, camera would focus on a different location.

The set of value (latitude and longitude) can be added as extras on the intent using `intent.putExtra("key", value)` and fetched using `getIntent().getSerializableExtra("value")`

Answer (score 0):

For example, you could do something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
i.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
i.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
startActivity(i);
```

And then in the `onCreate` method of your `MapActivity` class:

```
double latitude = (Double)  this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("latitude");
double longitude = (Double) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("longitude");
```

`